# How to make a horizontal color track underneath a vertical bar plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am trying to make a bar plot that looks like this: [vertical stacked barplot with a horizontal bar underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoJS7.png)

I made the actual vertical bar plot in python using this code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[15, 5])
width = 0.75   
ax.bar(labels, my_order["relapse"], width, label=SAMPLE[0], color = "r")
ax.bar(labels, my_order['remission'], width, bottom=my_order['relapse'], label=SAMPLE[1], color = "orange")
ax.set_title('Ratio of cells by patient in each cluster')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01,0.5), loc='center left')
```

`my_order` is a dataframe that contains a column with the numbers for relapse and a column for the numbers for remission. The part I cannot create is the horizontal bar underneath. This would be colored based on other properties of the different bars (each bar represents a cluster and in this case I would want to color the horizontal plot blue if the cluster has one property and yellow if it has another). Does anyone know if this is possible to do in python? Or if I have to do this manually? In the full dataset there are ~50 bars in the entire plot so it would be awesome to find a way to not do this manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through each bar position, and create a colored rectangle with the same width as the bar, but placed slightly below the plot.

The [rectangle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) has following parameters:

- `(x, y), width, height`
- `transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform()`: in the x-direction the values are measured in ["data coordinates"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html), here being `0, 1, 2, ...` for the bar positions; in the y-directions "axes coordinates" are used, going from 1 at the top to 0 at the bottom of the plot area and using negative for positions below
- `clip_on=False`: normally, when something is placed outside the plot area it is clipped away; `clip_on=False` overrides that behavior
- `facecolor=...`: the interior color
- `edgecolor='black'`: a black border

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

labels = [*'abcdefghijklmnopqrst']
my_order = pd.DataFrame({'relapse': np.random.randint(11, 51, 20),
                         'remission': np.random.randint(11, 51, 20),
                         'cluster': np.random.randint(1, 3, 20)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[15, 5])
width = 0.75
ax.bar(labels, my_order['relapse'], width, label='SAMPLE[0]', color='crimson')
ax.bar(labels, my_order['remission'], width, bottom=my_order['relapse'], label='SAMPLE[1]', color='orange')
ax.set_title('Ratio of cells by patient in each cluster')
legend1 = ax.legend(title='Samples', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.5), loc='center left')
ax.margins(x=0.01)
color_for_cluster = {1: 'skyblue', 2: 'yellow'}
for i, cluster in enumerate(my_order['cluster']):
    ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((i - width / 2, -0.1), width, 0.02,
                               facecolor=color_for_cluster[cluster], edgecolor='black',
                               transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), clip_on=False))
handles = [plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, facecolor=color_for_cluster[cluster], edgecolor='black', label=cluster)
           for cluster in color_for_cluster]
legend2 = ax.legend(handles=handles, title='Clusters', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, -0.01), loc='lower left')
ax.add_artist(legend1)  # add the legend again, because the second call to ax.legend removes the first legend
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot with rectangles]

You also could use `plt.Rectangle((i - 1/2, -0.1), 1, 0.02, ...)` to make the rectangles occupy the full width.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked great! Do you know how I could add a separate legend for the patch colors??

Comment: I actually figured out the second legend - thanks for the help!